# how do I print out one element from an object array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am trying to print out one object from the array of objects, the array contains 5 objects and I am asking how to print only one of the objects for example the store[1]?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Customer[] store = new Customer[5];
    Customer c = new Customer(1, "Szabi", "Master");
    Console console = new Console();
    store[0] = new Customer(1, "Szabi", "Finchley");
    store[1] = new Customer(2,"Anca", "Finchley") ;
    store[2] = new Customer (3, "Deniz","Cricklewood");
    store[3] = new Customer(4,"Suzanna", "Cricklewood") ;
    store[4] = new Customer (5, "Lavinia", "Ealing");


    //How do I print out just store[0] or just store[1]?
}
```

I am having trouble to print out at a certain index like for example store[1] or store[0] as it will always print out the value at store[4], no matter what I put in square brackets.
Customer class is as follows:

```
package Eldorado;

 import java.util.Arrays;

public class Customer implements CustomerItem , Comparable<Customer> {
static int id;
static String name;
static String address;


public Customer(){
id=0;
name=null;
address=null;
}
public Customer(int _id, String _name, String _address){
this.id=_id;
this.name=_name;
this.address=_address;
}
 public void setId(int _id){
this.id=_id;
}
public void setName(String _name){
this.name=_name;
}
public void setAddress(String _address){
this.address=_address;
}
 @Override
 public int getId(){
return id;
}@Override
public String getName(){
return name;
}@Override
public String getAddress(){
return address;
}@Override
public boolean equals(CustomerItem other){
Customer a = new Customer();
Customer b = new Customer();
if(a.compareTo(b)==0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}@Override
public int compareTo(Customer that){
if(this.id==that.id&&this.name==that.name&&this.address==that.address){
    return 0;
}else if(this.id>that.id){
return 1;
}else{
return -1;
 }
}
@Override
public String toString(){
return Integer.toString(getId())+getName()+getAddress();
}
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(store[1]);`!?

Comment: What happens when you pass`store[0]` or `store[1]` to printing method?

Comment: Is this a question?  What's stopping you from just using `store[0]` or `store[1]` when you go to print?

Comment: override `toString` in `Customer` class and do what @luk2302 mentioned

Comment: you mean if you pass stroe[0], then it should print 1, Szabi and Finchley?? Is that what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, to print out 1, Szabi, Finchley if I write System.out.println(store[0]); as at the moments is writes out the values of store[4], no matter what I put in quare brackets

Answer (score 3):

Use this `System.out.println(store[0]);`
However you should override the `toString` method to print what you want from the object, as the default method, inherited by the `Object` class doesn't print very useful information for your application, I imagine.